Power BI - using Switch to calculate subtotals
I've a measure where I'm using Switch to obtain different results.
The problem that I've is that if I filter the object by one of the values of the Switch individually I'm obtaining results but not the subtotals.
I show you:
enter image description here
At the Point 1 there are the levels that I've selected (both costs).
At the Point the Matrix where I can see it individually but not the subtotal (level "I").
I show you the measure:
Neto Analitica Unitario = IF(OR(SELECTEDVALUE(Analitica[Nivel1]) = "COSTE INDIRECTO CAMPO", SELECTEDVALUE(Analitica[Nivel1]) = "COSTE INDIRECTO SALIDAS"), CALCULATE([Neto Analitica Unitario Prev.]),SUMX(values(Articulo[FamiliaSuperior]), [Neto Analitica Unitario Prev.]))

This measure depends of this one where we've the Switch:
Neto Analitica Unitario Prev. = VAR _Calculo = SWITCH (
SELECTEDVALUE ( Analitica[Nivel1] ),
"VENTAS", DIVIDE([Total Venta Analitico], [Peso Neto Salidas]),
"COSTE DIRECTO ENTRADAS", [Coste Unitario Directo Entradas Año Natural],
"COSTE DIRECTO SALIDAS", DIVIDE( [Coste Directo Salida], [Peso Neto Salidas]),
"MARGEN BRUTO",
    ROUND(DIVIDE([Total Venta Analitico], [Peso Neto Salidas]),2)
        - ROUND([Coste Unitario Directo Entradas Año Natural],2) 
            - ROUND(DIVIDE( [Coste Directo Salida], [Peso Neto Salidas]),2),
"COSTE INDIRECTO SALIDAS", DIVIDE([Coste Indirecto Salidas] * ( -1 ), [Peso Neto Salidas]),
"COSTE INDIRECTO CAMPO", DIVIDE([Coste Indirecto Campo], [Peso Neto Salidas Proveedor Interno]) * (-1),
"COSTE DIRECTO CAMPO",[Coste Unitario Directo Campo Prev.],
"MARGEN NETO",
   ROUND(CALCULATE(ROUND(DIVIDE( [Total Venta Analitico], [Peso Neto Salidas]),2)
    - ROUND([Coste Unitario Directo Entradas Año Natural],2)
        - ROUND(DIVIDE( [Coste Directo Salida], [Peso Neto Salidas]),2)
             - ROUND(DIVIDE([Coste Indirecto Salidas] * ( -1 ), [Peso Neto Salidas]),2)
                + ROUND(DIVIDE([Coste Indirecto Campo], [Peso Neto Salidas Proveedor Interno]),2)
                    -  ROUND([Coste Unitario Directo Campo Prev.],2)),2))
        RETURN IF([Peso Neto Salidas] <> BLANK(), _Calculo, BLANK())

Do you know how I can obtain subtotals? Could be a problems between the relationship of the tables?

Wrap it in a SUMX similar to:
Neto Analitica Unitario Prev. = 
  var _Calculo =
    SUMX(
      DISTINCT(Analitica[Nivel1]),
      (
        SWITCH( Analitica[Nivel1],
          ...
        )
      )
    )

  return IF([Peso Neto Salidas] <> BLANK(), _Calculo, BLANK())

